# Change factor based on sample size

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) with an id column that looks like this:

| id |
| --- |
| a |
| a |
| a |
| a |
| b |
| b |

I want to change id based on number of entries. For example, if id is > 3, than c, so that the column then looks like this:

| id |
| --- |
| c |
| c |
| c |
| c |
| b |
| b |

id is a factor.

Comment: Could you clarify further what you are looking for? Based on your other recent question, it sounds like you want to provide different colors for a plot perhaps based on frequency of factor level? It might help to explain further. Do you want to keep 'a' as a factor level, or remove once replaced with 'c' (create new factor for `id`)? Maybe you just want to change the factor levels/labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide as much context as possible, to get accurate answer.
Your current question has the following answer:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(id = if_else(n() >= 3, "c", id))
```